# ROS Answers SE migration: perception pcl

Tags: ros, pcl, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Currently I am trying tutorial for PCL as described in http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl.php#using-pcl

But, as in perception_pcl package in ros I could not find file named "FindPCL.cmake".

Perhaps, someone could give some enlightenment here.
I am still a bit confused how to use pcl in ros.

Thanks in advanced.

Kang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9977/perception-pcl/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-18**:
In general it's best to add more detail to your headline. Try something like "Perception_pcl can't find FindPCL.cmake"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial you linked above is for using standalone PCL in your own CMake based project. It is not for using PCL within ROS.

If you are looking for how to use PCL in your own ROS nodes, see the [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) docs. In a nutshell, create a package as usual (this is described in the beginner tutorials elsewhere on ros.org), add a dependency on the `pcl_ros` package and then you should be able to include `pcl` headers into your package.

If you are trying to use standalone PCL in your own CMake based project outside of ROS and are having trouble, you should send an email to the pcl-users mailing list detailing the issues you are having.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS Indigo, if you want to use the standalone version of PCL, add following to include PCL headers before the ROS's default find packages:

```
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    geometry_msgs
    nav_msgs
    roscpp
    :
    :
    laser_geometry
)
add_executable(xyz src/xyz.cpp)
target_link_libraries(xyz ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

in addition to modifying your build and run dependencies in package.xml as per your requirements like pcl_msgs sensor_msgs ..

---

Originally posted by [ShubhamVerma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22795/shubhamverma/) with karma: 146 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1